# How to write HTL query to change the form input from text to tel

Tags: aem, sightly

I have customize form component. I have to change the input type of the form when it find html pattern="[+0-9()-]*" from text to tel. Is it possible using HTL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also see attribute documentation : https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/block-statements.html#attribute in this case `data-sly-attribute.type="${myModel.type}"` in your model you can decide whether you want `tel` or `text` based on the value submitted. if you want to change that while the user is entering data then you need to do in a clientlib as HTL is server side and not client side. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do these checks entirely in HTL expressions. You will need an Use Object that checks the input and exposes if it’s a telephone number or not:

```
<sly data-sly-use.myModel="...">
<input type="${myModel.isTelephone ? 'tel' : 'text'}"...
```